# is there a difference for example between : zoology facts and zoological facts?

Tags: grammar

I can't see any difference between the two, I would like someone who is advanced to shed some light ^^

Comment: The difference is that _zoology_ is a noun - the name of the subject - and _zoological_ the corresponding adjective, so _zoological facts_ is grammatically correct. However, it is possible to use a noun in an attributive manner, so _zoology facts_ could be understood to mean _facts pertaining to zoology_.

Comment: so, are they both correct ?

Comment: Read my edited comment (I accidentally hit return while composing it).

Comment: thank you so much for you input

Comment: Consider [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=biology+facts%2Cbiological+facts&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbiology%20facts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbiological%20facts%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbiology%20facts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbiological%20facts%3B%2Cc0) comparing written instances of ***biology facts*** and ***biological facts***. Because they're both *so* much more common than the corresponding ***zoology / zoological*** versions, you can *just about* see that the short form does occur occasionally. But relatively speaking, ***hardly ever***.

Comment: (That's to say, although ***zoology facts*** is *in principle* syntactically "valid", it's very rarely used, and should probably be avoided unless you know ***exactly why*** you don't want to do the same as almost everyone else.)

Comment: That's right. Any noun can be used as part of a noun compound (there are lots of categories: bahuvrihi, tatpurusha, etc). They have unpredictable meanings, because they're context-sensitive identifiers, and context varies; consider the difference in meaning between _pony ride_ and _snake bite_, for instance. So _zoology facts_ would be fine (say) in contrast to _statistics facts, mathematics facts,_ and _anthropology facts_, each referring to a different table in the Pick-A-Major display at a college. But that's a very special context.

Comment: The idea of a fact pertaining to zoology, seems strange to me. That horses have four legs? I’d just call that a fact. It might be a zoological observation — more so if one were reporting work on rare species — but zoology does not strike me as a discipline with a special stratum of truth. Chemistry and Physics, yes, as they diverge from the everyday.

Comment: Nothing like choosing an answer full of English mistakes. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, nouns can be used as attributes quite freely.
In "*zoology facts*",  "*zoology*" is a noun (substantive) qualifying  "*facts*".

The translation of such  a construction can be anything that generally relates "zoology" with "facts", for example:

- facts regarding zoology (as a science)
- facts from the point of view of zoology
- facts related in whatever way to zoology
- facts "belonging" to the general subject of zoology,
- et cetera

In the case of "*zoological facts*", "*zoological*" is an adjective. So, although the translation can be equivalent to the above, it can also be somewhat narrower: it can refers to facts that are zoological in nature.

**Examples:**

*A widely accepted zoology fact is that taxonomic classifications are complex.*

(Here I am saying that classifying animal species is difficult, and that such difficulty is a well-known fact about the science of zoology in general).

*A constant zoological fact is that carnivore animals eat other animals.*

Here "*animals eat other animals*" is an observation that pertains to zoology, hence, it is "zoological".
But it is not talking about zoology itself as a science and in general.

Sometimes, both forms acquire very distinct, idiomatic meanings, for example:

*I am taking political **economy** classes.*

I am taking classes on the subject of (political) economy.

*I am taking **economical** classes.*

I am being thrifty and taking classes that don't cost too much.

There is no general rule about when this happens, just the notion that adjectives (*zoological, economical*) tend to qualify more precisely and have specific meanings.

Comment: Please, I am taking **economics** classes. Also, economical means money saving, and economic is the adjective that accompanies an economy. So, an economic problem and an economical way to do shopping. These typical mistakes by speakers of some Romance languages....I wonder who upvoted this. Tsk tsk.

Comment: Gonzalo, I was not being mean above. It's just that translation is not always as simple as it seems, and you have found two false friends. That means a term that seems the same as in Spanish or French and in fact has a different meaning in one of the two languages....You are right that many times nouns function as adjectives.